# Comment: text formating Mostrar contenido de un menu con la funcion click de javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un menú de actividades y quiero que al hacer `click` en `a` la clase `active_tab` y `active_content` para la tabla `tbody` para que me muestre la información que ahí se aloja y que me remueva las clases de los mismos para no alterar el resultado.

Este es el código **JavaScript**, me funciona bien en la etiqueta `a` pero en la `tbody` solo me la remueve y no la agrega.

```
$(function() {

var menu = $(".activities_tab a");
var content = $("table tbody");

menu.click(function({
     menu.removeClass("active_tab");
     $(this).addClass("active_tab");
});
menu.click(function() {
     content.removeClass("active_content");
     $(this).addClass("active_content");
}); );
```

Y este es el código que esta ejecutando:

```
<td class="tcat" style="padding:0;" colspan="3">
    <span class="activities_tab">
        <a href="#latestposts" class="active_tab">
            <i style="font-size: 19px;" class="fas fa-home"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#marketplace">
            <i style="font-size: 19px;" class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#exclusive">
            <i style="font-size: 19px;" class="fas fa-certificate"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#reputation">
            <i style="font-size: 19px;" class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
        </a>
     </span>
  </td>
  <tbody class="content2 active_content" id="latestposts"></tbody>
  <tbody class="content2" id="exclusive"></tbody>
  <tbody class="content2" id="marketplac"></tbody>
  <tbody class="content2" id="reputation"></tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La lógica para aplicar el cambio de clases en la `a` y en los `tbody` es diferente, en la `a` puedes usar `this` por que es el elemento al cual le estas dando `click` pero para poder asignar y remover de forma correcta la clases en los `tbody` necesitas seleccionarlos directamente, para eso puedes utilizar el valor del atributo `href` de las etiquetas `a` ya que dicho valor contiene el `id` del elemento que debe mostrar:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".activities_tab a").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      
      $(".activities_tab a").removeClass("active_tab");
      $(this).addClass("active_tab");
       
      var atributo = $(this).attr('href');
      $(".content2").removeClass("active_content");
      $(atributo).addClass("active_content")
  });
});
```

```css
a.active_tab{
  color: blue;
}

.content2{
  display: none;
}

.content2.active_content{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <td class="tcat" style="padding:0;" colspan="3">
      <span class="activities_tab">
          <a href="#latestposts" class="active_tab">
              <i style="font-size: 19px;" class="fas fa-home"></i>
              latestposts
          </a>
          <a href="#marketplace">
              <i style="font-size: 19px;" class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              marketplace
          </a>
          <a href="#exclusive">
              <i style="font-size: 19px;" class="fas fa-certificate"></i>
              exclusive
          </a>
          <a href="#reputation">
              <i style="font-size: 19px;" class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
              reputation
          </a>
       </span>
    </td>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <tbody class="content2 active_content" id="latestposts">
    <td>latestposts</td>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="content2" id="exclusive">
    <td>exclusive</td>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="content2" id="marketplace">
    <td>marketplac</td>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="content2" id="reputation">
    <td>reputation</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```